# Reading unknown amount of lines at bottom of config file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I am creating a config file and using ConfigParser to parse the options in the config file. It will look something like this..

```
[Options]
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4

[Paths]
c:\windows
c:\documents
c:\testing
```

I am trying to find a way for the config parsing to read everything under the `Paths` sections and create some sort of dictionary or string of what is under it. It will be a unknown length of items.

Comment: What do you mean by "some sort"? What is your specific expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I basically want to put strings underneath a section such as the paths under the Paths section in the code example. Then I want to read all those paths into a single string. I just dont want to have to give each path a key like p1 = xxx, p2 = xxx